# To check/uncheck the checkbox using keyboard in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to let the user check/uncheck the checkbox on hitting either spacebar or enter in keyboard, I want to achieve this functionality using JavaScript function.

This is how my code looks partially:

```
 <span class="sample" onClick="UdateComponent" tabindex="0" role="checkbox" aria-checked="" aria-decribedby="">
```

Inside this span I want to include onkeypress or onkeydown for achieving the functionality that is mentioned above and the constraint is I only have to use JavaScript for this.

Comment: Why not use a checkbox, which has this functionality built in and can be styled just about any way you want?

Comment: I'm already using checkbox, but I'm not able to check/uncheck?

Comment: There is no checkbox in the markup above.

Comment: You should have an input tag inside of your span tag if you want to do it that way.

Comment: See also the `label` element.

Comment: is there a way to use onkeypress to achieve this? also I want only spacebar and enter to check/uncheck

Comment: @saisreereddy So you want to reinvent the wheel? Maybe you should create your own browser...

Answer (score 2):

**I would *strongly* recommend not doing this.** Use an `input type="checkbox"`, in combination with a `label`. It's what they're for. You can style them extremely thoroughly. You can even hide the `input type="checkbox"` if you want to and only show the `label`.

---

But you've said you can't use `input`. So yes, you can do this with a `keypress` handler. You'll presumably also want to handle clicks. See comments:

```js
// Handle toggline the "checkbox"
// Expects the element as `this` and the event as `e`
function toggleFakeCheckbox(e) {
  // States as far as I can tell from
  // https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-checked
  // and
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_checkbox_role
  this.setAttribute(
    "aria-checked",
    this.getAttribute("aria-checked") === "true" ? "false" : "true"
  );
  // Avoid the default (spacebar in particular is problematic)
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}

// Get the element
var sample = document.querySelector(".sample");

// Set up its handlers for click and keypress
sample.addEventListener("click", toggleFakeCheckbox);
sample.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  // Flag for whether to toggle
  var toggle = false;
  var keyCode;
  if ("key" in e) {
    // Modern user agent
    toggle = e.key === " " || e.key === "Enter";
  } else {
    // Fallback for older user agents
    keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
    toggle = keyCode === 32 || keyCode === 13;
  }
  if (toggle) {
    toggleFakeCheckbox.call(this, e);
  }
});
// Give it focus for easy testing
sample.focus();
```

```css
/* Let's show the state of the checkbox */
[role=checkbox][aria-checked=true]:before {
  content: '[x] '
}
[role=checkbox][aria-checked=false]:before {
  content: '[ ] '
}
```

```html
<span class="sample" tabindex="0" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" aria-decribedby="">Checkbox</span>
```

But again: Reinventing the wheel isn't a good thing, even if you try to respect all the ARIA rules when doing so...

**Update**: And sure enough, focussing the span in IE and hitting the space bar moves us to a different part of the page, even though we both prevented the default action (which was enough to stop that on Firefox) and stopped propagation. Why does it do that? Because we tried to reinvent the wheel. Which is a Bad Thing™.